# Labeling elements based on position in bag and extracting name of elements with max

Tags: apache-pig

I've already split the touple into a bag:

```
FOREACH sampleData GENERATE $0, (bag{tuple()}) TOBAG($1..) AS samples:bag{t:tuple()};
```

and I know how to find a max:

```
sampleMax = FOREACH sampleOfData GENERATE $0, MAX(samples);
```

But I'm trying to say "subelement_1" if the max is in param $0 of the bag. The issue is the bag size isn't necessary consistent.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: An example would much better illustrate the problem than generic code.

Comment: Sure. Let's say an example data set is "sample_1a b z x y z" where a b x y z are numbers I want to know which positions contain the max and so if z is the max the output is sample_1 value_3 value_6. Is that understandable?

Comment: Not sure how to do this in pure Pig but I can using a python UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you need an `argwhere()` function that takes into account duplicates.  You could use a python UDF for this.

**Data**:

```
(K1,{(K1,0),(K1,4),(K1,4),(K1,1)})
(K2,{(K2,5),(K2,5),(K2,1),(K2,2)})
```

**UDF**:

```
@outputSchema("max_idx:(index:int)")
def argmax_idx(bag):
    try:
        nums = [x[1] for x in bag]
        m = max(nums)
        idxs = tuple([i for i in xrange(len(nums)) if nums[i] == m])
        return idxs

    except:
        return tuple(None)
```

**Script**:

```
REGISTER 'argmax_idx.py' USING jython AS udf;

data = LOAD 'some_data';
A = FOREACH data GENERATE udf.argmax_idx(data);
DUMP A;
```

**Output**:

```
(K1, (1,2))
(K2, (0,1))
```

Note that `Pig` is zero indexed.

Comment: This makes sense thanks. I thought there might be a way without a UDF but your answer seems much more logical